How to calculate Gibbs free of a reaction?
I consider this reaction : NaOH (solid) + CO2 (gas) --> NaHCO3 (solid)
As far as I understand, Gibb free energy can be estimated like this:
Gibb = \delta(H) + \delta(ZPE) - T\delta(S)
\delta(H) = E(DFT_NaHCO3) - E(DFT_NaOH) - E(DFT_CO2)
because of solid phase, ZPE(NaHCO3) = ZPE(NaOH) = 0 and S(NaHCO3) = S(NaOH) = 0
\delta(ZPE) = ZPE(NaHCO3) - ZPE(CO2) - ZPE(NaOH) = -ZPE(CO2)
\delta(S) = S(NaHCO3) - S(CO2) - S(NaOH) = -S(CO2)
Overall, Gibb = E(DFT_NaHCO3) - E(DFT_NaOH) - E(DFT_CO2) - ZPE(CO2) + T * S(CO2)
Is this formula correct?

The biggest problem is that it's probably not wise to approximate the ZPE of solids as 0. There is no reason why you can neglect the ZPE of solids but not gases, because the ZPE is given by vibrations, and solids have vibrational modes just like gases do (actually solids have more vibrational degrees of freedom than gases of the same composition and mass). If you somehow cannot afford ZPE calculations of the solids, it's wiser to also neglect the ZPE of CO2, so you have some error cancellations from subtracting the ZPE contributions of CO2 and HCO3-.
Meanwhile you have also approximated the enthalpy as the energy (where you miss the $pV$ correction), and neglected the entropy of solids. While you may justify the latter because you don't want to do phonon calculations on the solids (because of program or computational resource limitations, for example), I see no reason why you don't include the $pV$ correction - it's small but it's available for free.

For solid-state materials, the entropy and volume change can be assumed ignorable

I see, this appears to be a valid reason for not including $pV$ of solids, but not a reason for neglecting the $pV$ for CO2. And the ZPE of solids still shouldn't be neglected IMHO
